Is there a way to influence how Coveo relevancy score is calculated?
We have a Coveo search box for our website to surface not just items from current website www.company.com, also surface results from other sister sites such as news.company.com etc.
The business requirement is that if the sort order relevancy is selected, we want the items from www.company.com showing up on top before all other items from sister sites.
What is the best way to tackle this problem? Right now, the sort of relevancy is based on the score on the search item, can we change how the score is calculated by assigning heavier weigh on items from www.company.com? or other approach to meet the business requirement?

You can easily configure a Query Ranking Expression (QRE) in a Coveo query pipeline to promote your items from www.company.com site, read more here
Alternatively, you can use a ranking function with a mathematical expression to evaluate URLs for each item returned by your query and generate some boost which then will added to the ranking score of that item. See a ranking function example here.
